# Example of probability rule

Tags: probability

Can someone provide me with an example (real life example, if possible) in which $P(a \cap b) < P(a) \times P(b)$?

Comment: What if $B = A^c$? Or, for a "real-life" example, suppose that I am planning on rolling a fair die and I choose $A$ as the event that the outcome is an even number and $B$ the event that the outcome is a prime number.  Then, $$P(A\cap B) = P(\{2\}) = \frac 16 < P(A)\times P(B) = \frac 12 \times \frac 12 = \frac 14.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event "I ate cereal for breakfast" and $B$ be the event "shortly after waking up I felt like eating toast"

I contend that

$P(A \cap B) < P(A)\times P(B)$

The argument goes like this -- I'm less likely to end up eating cereal when I felt like toast than I am to eat cereal "overall" (i.e. without accounting for my previous feeling about what I'd like), and as a result, $P(A|B)<P(A)$, so

$P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)P(B)<P(A)P(B)$

Indeed, think of any other real word situation where $P(A|B)<P(A)$, and

$P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)P(B)<P(A)P(B)$.

so if A is "it rains" and B is "the weather report predicted it to be sunny", that would be another. Or if A is "votes Republican" and B is "is a registered Democrat" or A is "wins the lottery" and B is "doesn't buy a ticket in the lottery".

Comment: Glen_b, I couldn't be more happier with this beautiful answer!